# Wget ANSI Error

Tags: linux, wget

I am trying to recursively download files from a specific website and I am encountering an error I've never seen before and which google comes up blank on. The command I'm entering is:

```
wget -m -p -E -k -K -np http://www.slac.stanford.edu/~timb/500/1f_3f_production/ae_1f/E0500-TDR_ws.Pae_ea.Gwhizard-1.95.eB.pL.I37470/
```

and the output is:

```
Conversion from 'ANSI_X3.4-1968' to 'ANSI_X3.4-1968' isn't supported
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  wget -m -p -E -k -K -np
```

The error seems to occur no matter what arguments I use. More strangely, it has no problems if I download each file in the directory individually. Does anybody have an idea what this error means?

Comment: It is a bug in `wget`  (or some libraries used by it). Try to upgrade. Try also using `curl` as a workaround. BTW, my `wget` version 1.16 don't have that bug and can run your command, so perhaps upgrade your `wget`

Comment: I've upgraded the my system and I now have the same version as you. The ansi error is gone, but I am still unable to download more than one file at a time. Any attempt to do so merely creates a directory path to where I want to download from, as well as an index.html. (Note that I tried the above command with and without the -r flag)

Answer (score 0):

Your exact command works for me on Windows 7 CMD line. I get 9 files. Google reports some problems with zsh. Can you try bash?

Comment: The problem occurs with both bash and zsh. I'm curious why you got 9 files, as there were at least 13 in that particular directory.